# footer won't stack at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

In this code I'm trying to make a footer to be under the red background tea list, but I can't. Even when I set `position` to `absolute` and `bottom` to `0px`, it gets to the bottom of the page not under everything. I don't understand where the problem is coming from: the list or the body in the style element. I tried a lot of changes but nothing works

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

<style>
   
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {

    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    
}
.dd {
background-color: rgb(209, 15, 15);
width: 65%;
height: fit-content;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;

}

.dd > a {
border: solid blue 3px;
position: relative;
width: fit-content;
height: fit-content;
margin: 1px;
padding: 0;

}
.dd img {
border: solid rgb(212, 0, 255) 3px;
position: relative;
display: flex;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;

}

.foot{
background-color: lawngreen;
position: absolute;
height: 100px;
margin-top: -100px;
clear: both;
display: block;
bottom: 0px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dd">
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>

    <footer class="foot" aria-placeholder="hello"> hello</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something more like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dtv3q2kc/)?

Comment: yes sir that what am looking for but i don't see the changes you made

Comment: Look at the `foot` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this:**

```
{
position : fixed; bottom : 0; }
```

Comment: This will make a sticky footer that is always showing if the page content is longer than the viewport, and it would sit on top of the red content. Is that what you were trying to do @Hesham?

Answer (score 1):

You're close! Replace the content of your `body` and `.foot` CSS to match these and it will work:

```
body {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.foot {
background-color: lawngreen;
position: absolute;
height: 100px;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

The key changes to make that work are:

- **Add `position: relative` to `body`**--in order to use `absolute` positioning on the footer, you need to tell it what it's positioned relative to by setting the ancestor you want to `position: relative`. ([reference](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp))
- **Change `height: 100vh` to `min-height: 100vh`**--when your content overflows 100% of the browser, that will throw off the layout. Instead, use `min-height` to ensure that potential empty space is filled in the body and the footer can be pushed to the bottom of the browser window.
- **Add padding to the bottom of `body`**--Add `padding-bottom: 100px` to `body` to account for the footer and ensure that no content is covered by the footer. I assume this is what you were attempting to do by using `margin-top: -100px` on `.foot`, so I also removed that.
- **Add `width: 100%` to `.foot`**--in order for the `absolute` positioned element to fill the entire screen horizontally, add this CSS.

Full snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

<style>
   
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.dd {
background-color: rgb(209, 15, 15);
width: 65%;
height: fit-content;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;

}

.dd > a {
border: solid blue 3px;
position: relative;
width: fit-content;
height: fit-content;
margin: 1px;
padding: 0;

}
.dd img {
border: solid rgb(212, 0, 255) 3px;
position: relative;
display: flex;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;

}

.foot{
background-color: lawngreen;
position: absolute;
height: 100px;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
}
.container {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dd">
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="aa" href="page.html" > <img class="ii" src="2.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <footer class="foot" aria-placeholder="hello"> hello</footer>
</body>
</html>
```